# Modify Odoo Discussions (mail)

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I’ve been trying to modifying the Odoo discussions with no success.

This is what I’m trying to achieve:[image]

I add messages with the "New Message" button to an Odoo module (in class mro.order).
The messages are showing up in the Discussions module:
[image]

But I need the title to be like ‘MRO00049 – Foliemast gaat steeds in alarm’ instead of just MRO00049.
So I need mro_order.name – mro_order.omschrijving in the title.
How can I change this?

I've been looking for a few hours everywhere in the code of the MRO module and the mail module but don't know how to do it...

I already found the title is in /mail/static/src/xml/thread.xml:

```
<t t-if="message.model &amp;&amp; (message.model != 'mail.channel') &amp;&amp; options.display_document_link">
    on <a t-att-href="message.url" t-att-data-oe-model="message.model" t-att-data-oe-id="message.res_id"><t t-esc="message.record_name"/></a>
</t>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to override the default `name_get` function on `mro.order` and return the name in your preferred format, as [`name_get()` is used](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py#L680) to fill [default value for `record_name` on newly created `mail.message` records without this value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/4ca6945256f9353ab7f9633552872fd1fa7fdaca/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py#L724), eg.:

```py
from odoo import api, models


class MroOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mro.order'

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        for rec in self:
            result.append((rec.id, u'%s - %s' % (rec.name, rec.description)))
        return result
```

I am not familiar with `mro.order` object, so I have assumed that by `omschrijving` field name you have meant `description`.

Note that this change will apply only to newly created messages (no effect on old messages).

Comment: Sorry didn't get a chance to try it out yet. Just tested your exact code and worked out of the box! Thanks!